# Datatables in asp.net core Unknown Parameter but correct number of columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, datatables

I am using datatables in a asp.net core web site however I am getting the following error.

> 4. Warning: Requested unknown parameter.

I have the correct number of columns the only thing I think is throwing it off is the edit and delete buttons but its from the https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-datatables-grid-with-asp-net-mvc/ tutorial here.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#example").DataTable({
        "processing": true, // for show progress bar    
        "serverSide": true, // for process server side    
        "filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)    
        "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once    
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/Bookings/LoadData",
            "type": "POST",
            "datatype": "json"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "id", "name": "Id", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "name", "name": "Name", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "startDate", "name": "StartDate", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "endDate", "name": "EndDate", "autoWidth": true },          
            {
                "render": function (data, type, full, meta) { return '<a class="btn btn-
           info" href="/Demo/Edit/' + full.id + '">Edit</a>'; }
            },
            {
                data: null, render: function (data, type, row) {
                    return "<a href='#' class='btn btn-danger' onclick=DeleteData('" + 
               row.id + "'); >Delete</a>";
                }
            }
        ]

    });
});


function DeleteData(CustomerID) {
 if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete ...?")) {
    Delete(CustomerID);
  } else {
    return false;
 }
}


function Delete(CustomerID) {
 var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "DemoGrid/Delete";

  $.post(url, { ID: CustomerID }, function (data) {
    if (data) {
        oTable = $('#example').DataTable();
        oTable.draw();
    } else {
        alert("Something Went Wrong!");
    }
 });
}
```

I am loading my data as follows

```
public IActionResult LoadData()
{         
            var draw = HttpContext.Request.Form["draw"].FirstOrDefault();

            // Skip number of Rows count  
            var start = Request.Form["start"].FirstOrDefault();

            // Paging Length 10,20  
            var length = Request.Form["length"].FirstOrDefault();

            // Sort Column Name  
            var sortColumn = Request.Form["columns[" + Request.Form["order[0]
            [column]"].FirstOrDefault() + "][name]"].FirstOrDefault();

            // Sort Column Direction (asc, desc)  
            var sortColumnDirection = Request.Form["order[0][dir]"].FirstOrDefault();

            // Search Value from (Search box)  
            var searchValue = Request.Form["search[value]"].FirstOrDefault();

            //Paging Size (10, 20, 50,100)  
            int pageSize = length != null ? Convert.ToInt32(length) : 0;

            int skip = start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;

            int recordsTotal = 0;

            // getting all Customer data  
            string fieldsToSelect = "new Session { Name = p.Name }"; //Pass this as parameter.


            var customerData = sessionDb.GetAllSessions().ToList();
            List<SessionGridViewModel> sessionGridViewModelsList = new List<SessionGridViewModel>();
            foreach (var session in customerData)
            {
                SessionGridViewModel vm = new SessionGridViewModel();
                vm.Id = session.Id;
                vm.Name = session.Name;
                vm.StartDate= session.StartDate;
                vm.EndDate= session.EndDate;
                sessionGridViewModelsList.Add(vm);

            }
            var sessionData = sessionGridViewModelsList;
            //Sorting  
            if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumnDirection)))
            {
               // customerData = customerData.OrderBy(sortColumn + " " + sortColumnDirection);
            }
            //Search  
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchValue))
            {
                //customerData = customerData.Where(m => m.Name == searchValue);
            }

            //total number of rows counts   
            recordsTotal = sessionData.Count();
            //Paging   
            var data = sessionData.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
            //Returning Json Data  
          return Json(new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = recordsTotal, 
          recordsTotal = recordsTotal, data = data });
}
```

My Grid view model is basically.

```
public class SessionGridViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

My Html of my page is

```
 <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" 
  width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id </th>
            <th>Name </th>
            <th>StartDate </th>
            <th>EndDate</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

So why un earth am I getting the error that leads me here. 4. Warning: Requested unknown parameterhttps://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4

**Edit 2**

Their seems to be extra column called prototype being added on

[image]

Comment: You can [edit] the question to show the complete text of the error message, and also to show what results you find after following the diagnosis and resolution steps provided in the error message's link.

Comment: It can also be helpful to show us a sample of the JSON response (as text), so we can see its overall structure, and what some sample row data looks like.

Comment: Please see edits

Comment: Please show the JSON as text, not as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out what it was was this line I changed it from an anchor tag to a input type of button as is now working as expected.

```
{
 data: null, render: function (data, type, row) {
  return '<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  onclick=Edit(' + 
  row.id + ') value="edit"/><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" 
   onclick=DeleteData('+row.id + ') value="Delete"/>'
}
```